# SQL Server : View permission to table

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, schema, multi-tenant

Is it possible to grant a user access to a view but restrict the user from accessing the table the view selects from?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tUsers](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TenantID] int
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE VIEW [scmTenant1].[vUsers]
AS
SELECT     ID, Username, Password
FROM         dbo.tUsers
WHERE        TenantID = 1
```

The SQL Server user account (`usrTenant1`) has access to schema `scmTenant1` but does not have access to the `dbo` schema. I log into SQL Server Management Studio as `usrTenant1` and try executing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM scmTenant1.vUsers
```

Gives me error:

> *The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tUsers', database 'Sandbox', schema 'dbo'.*

If I grant this account access to the `dbo` schema the query executes fine.

I think what I would really like to grant the view permission to the table. But my question is can you grant a user access to a view and restrict that user from accessing the underlying table the view selects from?

Answer (score 2):

If you make the owner of the view dbo rather than scmTenant - or create an intermediate view that does the same - then you can grant permission to the view without granting permissions to the underlying table.

ie

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vUsers_T1
AS 
SELECT     ID, Username, Password 
FROM         dbo.tUsers 
WHERE        TenantID = 1

CREATE VIEW [scmTenant1].[vUsers] as
SELECT * FROM dbo.vUsers_T1
```

Alternately, you could create a function that returns the ID of the current tenant and create a view that refers to that in dbo.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vUsers
AS 
SELECT     ID, Username, Password 
FROM         dbo.tUsers 
WHERE        TenantID = dbo.GetCurrentTenant()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I don't think this will work in my environment. I plan on creating a Schema and View for every tenant in my system. If I move the View to dbo than each tenant's view will need a unique name which will break my code.

Comment: Replaced dbo.GetCurrentTenant() with SUSER_SID() and altered the table replacing TenantID with SID. This column has a default value of SUSER_SID(). Works great, thank you!